# .net core 3 web api controller - code execution after sending response

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 3.1 webapi project. In some controllers, I need to execute some code that doesn't impact the response to the client.

In particular, I have a method that returns a json with a profile's information, which is called when user visits that profile's page. After get profile's information, I need to log that a user visits this page, but, for a faster response, I want to return response before this log operation.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProfilesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Profile>> GetProfileById([FromRoute] int id)
        {
             Profile profile = await _profileService.GetByIDAsync(id);

             // DO THIS OPERATION IN BACKGROUND AND DON'T WAIT TO RETURN RESPONSE
              await _logService.LogProfileVisit(id);

             return Ok(profile);
        }
}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `await`, and you are no longer waiting for the response.

Comment: You can't just remove the `await` if `_logService` is Scoped.  As it will be destroyed at the end of request processing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `await` keyword before `_logService.LogProfileVisit(id);`

This will prevent you from waiting for response

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProfilesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Profile>> GetProfileById([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        _logService.LogProfileVisit(id);
        Profile profile = await _profileService.GetByIDAsync(id);
        return Ok(profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Farhard

thanks for your reply.

I tried this solution but it doesn't work because I think that when the webapi return the response, the context of the database (I use Entity Framework) is disposed and therefore pending operations are not completed.

Comment: @Marco Of course. in .net core `DI` disposed `DbContext` after executing action. if `LogProfileVisit` works with `DbContext` maybe an error occurs

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Use a framework such as HangFire or Quartz Scheduler that brings this functionality. This might make sense if you'll be needing to use this feature in more than a few places. Otherwise, they're rather heavy.
2. Use `Task.Run()` in conjuction with `ScopeFactory`.

For the second option, the basic code would look like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Profile>> GetProfileById([FromRoute] int id)
{
     Profile profile = await _profileService.GetByIDAsync(id);

     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         await _logService.LogProfileVisit(id);
     }

     return Ok(profile);
}
```

This will crash. As soon as the controller returns it will dispose of all the services, including `_logService`' leading to an error.
The solution is to use `IServiceScopeFactory` to create a scoped service that will be disposed when the task ends:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Profile>> GetProfileById([FromRoute] int id)
{
     Profile profile = await _profileService.GetByIDAsync(id);

     Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
         var _logService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<LogService>();
         await _logService.LogProfileVisit(id);
     }

     return Ok(profile);
}
```

For a complete example of this implementation see this [post](https://michaelceber.medium.com/net-core-web-api-how-to-correctly-fire-and-forget-database-commands-from-controller-end-point-cad7a879630).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with filter for example. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use many approach but there is no single line solution for that. You can use background workers to achive that. "Bakcground service with hosted Service in .NET Core" may suit your needs. You can also use a library like Hangfire for easily configurable complicated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to run task in background without waiting response.

Example using HangFire :

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => _logService.LogProfileVisit(id));
```